# Why is original method mocked by GoogleMock still getting called?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have been attempting to use GoogleMock to override a few specific methods in a underlying class, however I seem to be getting the base constructor, rather than the mocked object. Is there something obvious I am missing here?

I have been following the following example:
http://blog.divebomb.org/2011/07/my-first-c-cmake-googletest-and-googlemock/

However, in my test, I am still getting my 'printf' called. Any thoughts?

Here are the classes/header files:

*A.h*:

```
#pragma once
class A
{
public:
    virtual void methodToOverride();
    void someConcreteMethod();

    int mMemberVariable;
};
```

*A.cpp*:

```
#include "A.h"

void A::methodToOverride()
{
    std::printf("Hello World");
}

void A::someConcreteMethod()
{
}
```

*B.h*:

```
#include "A.h"

class B
{
public:
    B(A &injectedClass);
    ~B();
    void MethodToTest();

private:
    A mA;
};
```

*B.cpp*:

```
#include "B.h"

B::B(A & injectedClass):mA(injectedClass)
{
    mA.someConcreteMethod();
}

B::~B(){}

void B::MethodToTest()
{
    mA.methodToOverride();
}
```

*MockA.h*:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "gmock\gmock.h"

class MockA : public A
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(methodToOverride, void());

};
```

BTest.cpp:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "MockA.h"
#include "B.h"

using ::testing::AtLeast;
using ::testing::_;

TEST(BTest, mockObject)
{
    // Arrange
    MockA injectedMock;
    EXPECT_CALL(injectedMock, methodToOverride())
        .Times(AtLeast(1));

    B classUnderTest(injectedMock);

    // Act
    classUnderTest.MethodToTest();
}
```

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude re-posted the question, deleting original, with exact code here... if you have any insights they would be appreciated!

Comment: @doctorlove reposted from previous question

Comment: Please don't delete and repost the same question. Edit the existing question instead. That will also push the question back on to the front page again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major problem is that `B::mA` is an *instance* of the `A` class. It doesn't know anything about child-classes and objects.

The member `B::mA` either needs to be a reference or a pointer for polymorphism to work.

Comment: So... when I went down the reference/pointer road, it was fine when the method wasn't used... but when I tried to use an "EXPECT" call, it ended up getting weird stack errors (specifically an error around the stack pointer not matching correctly). Is there a better way to accomplish this using Google Mock?